# AWS DMS replicate only selected columns

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, cdc, dms

I'm using AWS DMS to CDC from MySQL on-premise database to AWS S3.

1. Is it feasible to transfer only a few columns from the source table to target? I have a table with more than 50 columns and only need 10.
2. If I want to transfer 5 tables from the source, is it best practice to create 1 replication task for each table, or put all 5 in one?

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes, by using [transformations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Transformations.html).
2. If your replication tasks are full-load-and-cdc, then, definitely no. Because each replication task will end up with the redo logs being transferred to your replication instance, consuming memory CPU power, and network bandwidth.

Comment: I'm not sure how transformations help with #1. You can only filter out data based on some column condition, but not refrain from migrating certain columns altogether

Comment: @TheLifeOfParallax Try the below. I'm using it in my production code.
`{
  "rule-type": "transformation",
  "rule-id": "1",
  "rule-name": "1",
  "rule-action": "include-column",
  "rule-target": "column",
  "object-locator": {
    "schema-name": "YourSchema",
    "table-name": "YourTable",
    "column-name": "YourColumn"
  }
}
`

Answer (score 1):

1. You can do that by creating filter conditions. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pcYxB8ATtec) will help you out.
2. That is totally up to you. No matter how replication tasks are created, it works normally. If your tables are so different from each one, you can consider separating them.